# Mixing glass and emission shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I want my emission material to also be the colour green, but I'm not sure how to do it, here is a copy of my node layout at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The output of nodes can be connected to more than one nodes, so you can use it on your glass too.
[image]

Comment: My output node only allows either the emission or the glass to be connected to the surface of the output

Comment: @weinbecher see new image:

Answer (score 4):

Your problem comes from having the emission node strength set to *500*. 
Anything over 1 will render white.

You can do two things to fix that.
One, the simple way is just to lower the strength of the emission node down to 1. That will make it look shadeless, but will still have your green gradient.

Or
You can add in a node setup like this, which will keep your very bright emission source, but to the camera render your glass node. (it would still look better with the emission strength lowered.)
[image: cycles nodes]
Notice the selected nodes, the *Light Path* node's *Is Camera Ray* output is used as the mix factor for the new *Mix* node. All *Is Camera Ray* does is determine what rays are coming from the camera.